# Text is writing code

Tags: text, marquee

I want to add on my site a text who is writing, as in http://www.whoismrrobot.com/
I use the code `<Marquee>Text Here</Marquee>` but this code only rolls the text.

Answer (score 0):

The effect on [your example site](http://www.whoismrrobot.com/) is not achieved with the marquee tag, and it can't be done this way. I guess the site is using some combination of JavaScript, CSS and maybe server side scripting.

Generally using the marquee tag is a bad idea, as it is some remnant of the "old times", when format and content both were provided by the html page itself. Even back then the marquee tag wasn't part of the html-specification and not supported by every browser.

For further details see [this description](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_marquees.htm) of the tag.